# How to use wildcard in AWS Principal?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Currently I have policy role like:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
   {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
      "AWS": [
         "arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/a111-ml-role/some-api-v2",
         "arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/a111-ml-role/some-api-v1"
      ],
     "Service": [
        "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com",
        "glue.amazonaws.com",
        "comprehend.amazonaws.com",
        "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    },
   "Action": [
       "sts:AssumeRole",
       "sts:TagSession"
    ]
   }
 ]
}
```

So I want to replace V1 and V2 with V*(wildcard) because I want to have multiple resources.
How can I achieve this? Tried using Condition but it didn't work out.

I.E
Instead of

```
"AWS": [
         "arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/a111-ml-role/some-api-v2",
         "arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/a111-ml-role/some-api-v1"
      ],
```

I want something like this:

```
"AWS": [
         "arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/a111-ml-role/some-api-v*""
      ],
```

Comment: Other than the wildcards `"*"` and `"AWS": "*"`, you cannot use a wildcard to match part of a principal name or ARN.

Comment: Yes I know and I am looking for something to replace it. Because if I just write `"AWS": "*"`   there is so many access

Comment: Investigate making "AWS": "*" the principal but then adding a Deny condition if the Principal ARN presented does not match your wildcard. Have not tested this, may not work. Also, perhaps you could simply automate this: trigger a Lambda function based on CloudTrail Logs for IAM actions (add/delete role) associated with role names that match your wildcard and update the policy by adding/removing the relevant full ARN.

Comment: You mean smth like:
`Effect: "Deny"
Principal: { "AWS": "*"}
Condition: {
    "StringNotLike": {
           "arn:aws:sts::/my_role_*"
}`

Comment: That's the idea, but again not tested so with you to investigate. But you would use a policy condition key like [aws:PrincipalArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-principalarn).

Comment: Yes, I did like you said but now it gives me an error with an access denied ended with `with an explicit deny`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html):

> You cannot use a wildcard to match **part of** a principal name or ARN.

You would have to explicitly list out all of your versions:

```
"AWS": [
         "arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/a111-ml-role/some-api-v3",
         "arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/a111-ml-role/some-api-v2",
         "arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/a111-ml-role/some-api-v1"
      ],
```

Comment: Yes I can but I don't want to. I want to have one version with * which suits all variants.